# emulator app only showing title, not matching eclipse preview

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a simple GUI table-layout I'm trying to design in eclipse, but when I run the app in the emulator, only the title of my application appears. Nothing else that is shown from the eclipse graphical layout window shows up in the emulator. I've also tried it on my real device with the same outcome, so I suspect I'm doing something wrong with the code. 
Here is the code from the main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="1.0">
<TableLayout 
android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableRow
    android:layout_weight=".2"
    android:layout_height="0px" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:background="@drawable/my_shape_file"> 
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2" 
    android:layout_weight=".001">
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button2" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button3" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:id="@+id/button4"></Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button5" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>    
    <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:baselineAligned="true" 
    android:layout_weight=".02" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout2" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5">                                 
            <TableRow
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4" 
            android:layout_height="0dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1">             
                <Button 

                android:id="@+id/button6" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/second_button">
                </Button>
                <Button 
                android:text="Button" 
                android:id="@+id/button7" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                </Button>
                <Button 
                android:text="Button" 
                android:id="@+id/button8" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                </Button>
            </TableRow>                     
            <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5"         
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:layout_height="0dp">
                <Button             
                android:id="@+id/button9" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/second_button">
                </Button>
                <Button 
                android:text="Button" 
                android:id="@+id/button10" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                </Button>
                <Button 
                android:text="Button" 
                android:id="@+id/button11" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                </Button>
            </TableRow> 
        </TableLayout>           
    <TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout3" 
    android:layout_width="0dp" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".33">        
    </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
    android:layout_weight=".01"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow6">
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button12" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button12" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button13" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button14" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button15" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
    android:layout_weight=".01"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow7">
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button16" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button17" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button18" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button19" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button20" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
    android:layout_weight=".01"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow8">
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button21" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button22" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button23" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button24" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button25" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>        
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
    android:layout_weight=".01"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow9">
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button26" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button27" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button28" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button29" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button30" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
    android:layout_weight=".01"
    android:id="@+id/tableRow10" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dp">
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button31" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button32" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button33" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button34" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button35" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
    android:layout_weight=".01"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow11">
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button36" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button37" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button38" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button39" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button40" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
    android:layout_weight=".01"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow12">
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button41" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button42" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button43" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button44" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:id="@+id/button45" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I suggest you to check if the emulator settings is the same than your livepreview settings. But really didnt trust the livepreview on eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you've specified `setContentView(R.layout.main)` in the onCreate of your Activity.

There should also be a closing tag for LinearLayout at the end of the document.

Other than those two issues, this layout works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your main activity, do you ever call ... ?

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

--preferably in your OnCreate() method

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your xml , it do correct。
You may forget to `setContentView(R.layout.main);` in `OnCreate()` in you main Activity.